# R- Connecting the maximum and the minimum value of two adjacent categorical variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot now. Each color represent a categorical group and each group has a range of values which are on the x-axis. There should not be any overlapping between the range of categorical variables. However, because of the thickness of scatter points, it looks like that there is overlapping. So, I want to draw a line to connect the maximum point of the group and the minimum point of the adjacent group so that as long as the line does not have a negative slope, it can show that there is no overlapping between each categorical variable.

I do not know how to use geom_line() to connect two points where y-coordinate is a categorical variable. IS that possible to do so??

Any help would be appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### **My reading comprehension failed me, so I misunderstood the question. Ignore this answer unless you want to learn about the `lineend =` argument of `geom_line`.**

---

```
# generate dummy data
df <- data.frame(xvals = runif(1000, 0, 1))

# these categories were chosen to line up 
#   with tick marks to show they don't overlap
df$cats <- cut(df$xvals, c(0, .25, .625, 1))) 

ggplot(df, aes(xvals, cats, colour = cats)) + 
  geom_line(size = 3)
```

[image]

The caveat is there there is a `lineend =` argument to `geom_line`. The default is `butt`, so that lines end exactly where you want them to and butt up against things, but sometimes that's not the right look. In this case, the other options would cause visual overlap, as you can see with the gridlines.

With `lineend = "square"`:
[image]

With `lineend = "round"`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `geom_segment` not `geom_line`. You'll need to aggregate your data into a new data frame that has the points you want plotted. I adapted Brian's sample data and use `dplyr` for this:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(xvals = runif(50, 0, 1))
df$cats <- cut(df$xvals, c(0, .25, .625, 1))

# aggregation
library(dplyr)
df_summ = df %>% group_by(cats) %>%
    summarize(min = min(xvals), max = max(xvals)) %>%
    mutate(adj_max = lead(max),
           adj_min = lead(min),
           adj_cat = lead(cats))

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(xvals, cats, colour = cats)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_segment(data = df_summ, aes(
        x = max,
        xend = adj_min,
        y = cats,
        yend = adj_cat
    ))
```

[image]

You can keep the segments colored as the previous category, or maybe set them to a neutral color so they don't stand out as much.

Comment: I completely misread the question, so your answer is correct! I'm going to delete mine, but feel free to keep the dummy data :)